# Display the Configurable product name in Simple product edit page

Tags: magento2.4.5p1

How to create a magento module that has the function: display the Configurable product name in its own Simple product edit page.

Example:

This is the Configurable product
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNgxe.png

It have list the simple product
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAy6b.png

I want simple edit page them have row display name of the Configurable product
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCCa1.png